# .htaccess - How to redirect URL to a folder and then to a PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am setting up a cache system for my blog (not a WordPress) and I want to store the cached files in a `posts/` folder, so I don't fill my root folder with post files.

I have a file called `post.php` that creates these posts files if the slug corresponds to an actual post in a different website (I check this with WordPress REST API). So when I visit `mywebsite.com/slug-to-post` and this URL doesn't match any of my files on the root level, it fallbacks to `post.php` using `FallbackResource post.php` in `.htaccess`, and `post.php` uses this slug to create a cached version and stores it, but since there can be thousands of posts, I don't want the files to be stored in the root level, but in `posts/name-of-the-file`.

So that file would be accessed via `mywebsite.com/posts/slug-to-post` but for SEO purposes I still want it to be `mywebsite.com/slug-to-post`.
What should I write in my .htaccess to fallback any unknown file to the `posts/` folder, and if the file doesn't exists there, fallback again to `post.php`, which is stored on root level?

Nothing I've tried has worked so far.
To cache the files I'm using the code present here: https://phppot.com/php/php-cache-for-dynamic-web-pages/

**UPDATE:** This is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/posts/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.php)$ /posts/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.php$ post.php [L]
```

Comment: How does `slug-to-post` map to a file? Is this a filename?

Comment: Yes, `slug-to-post` is the name of the cached file, so it would be something like `root dir/posts/slug-to-post.php`

Comment: "Nothing I've tried has worked so far." - it would be useful to see what you have already tried. Sometimes it may only require a slight change to existing directives, or it could perhaps indicate a conflict with existing directives if the directives appear OK (which is a common issue).

Comment: This is my current `.htaccess` file: 
```RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/posts/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.php)$ /posts/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.php$ post.php [L]```

As I mentioned on your answer, now `mywebsite.com/post-slug.php` works but `mywebsite.com/post-slug` throws a 404 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting a file of the form `/<post-slug>`, which either:

1. Maps to a file of the form `/<post-slug>.php` in the document root.
2. OR, maps to a cached version of this file of the form `/posts/<post-slug>.php`.
3. Otherwise, the request should fallback to `/post.php` in the document root.

Try something like the following (using mod_rewrite) in addition to your `FallbackResource` directive:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# 1. Check for file in the document root
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L]

# 2. Check for cached version in the "/posts" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/posts/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /posts/$1.php [L]

# 3. Request does not map to a file, so fallback to "/post.php"
FallbackResource /post.php
```

This does assume that your `<post-slug>` does not contain dots (`.`). This makes it easier to avoid conflicts with static resource or create an unnecessary filesystem check after rewriting the request to `<post-slug>.php`. If the `<post-slug>` can contain dots then we'll need to alter the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and add an additional *condition*.

NB: MultiViews needs to be disabled for this to work properly (it may already be disabled on your server).

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

Just a few notes on your original rule block.

- If you make the `RewriteRule` *pattern* more restrictive, rather than matching *anything* (ie. `.*`) then you can probably avoid the condition that checks that the request does not map to a filesystem directory. (Is a request for a filesystem directory ever a valid request?)
- A literal dot in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* (1st argument) does not need to be backslash escaped. This is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.
- Note that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` is not necessarily the same as the (potentially) rewritten URL `$1.php` - it will depend on the request and the filesystem (since `REQUEST_FILENAME` is calculated *after* the request has been mapped to the filesystem), but since you are allowing anything (ie. `.*`) then there is potential for error here.
- The `NC` flag is superfluous, since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is not case-sensitive anyway.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply.


Here's the problem now: 
Let's say there is a `post-slug.php` file in my `posts` folder, being the path this one:
`mywebsite.com/posts/post-slug.php`. 
Now, with the new `.htaccess`, if i go to `mywebsite.com/post-slug`, I got a 404 response, but if I go to `mywebsite.com/post-slug.php`, it  works.

So I need to add a .php to the $1, something like
`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/posts/$1.php -f`

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ah, OK, that does make more sense. :) Your URLs are extensionless... the user requests `/post-slug` (they never actually request `/post-slug.php` directly), but this maps to `/post-slug.php` internally. I've rewritten my answer. (Do you need to handle the situation if the user should request `/post-slug.php` directly? eg. Have these `.php` URLs been indexed by search engines or linked to by third parties?)

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my late reply! I managed to get it working with your last answer, thank you very much!